# Scaling an image

Tags: image-processing

I have a fundamental question about image scaling/downsizing algorithms available in CSS/HTML. Both in the case of image scaling and image downsizing, is an integer scaling better than a non integer scaling. Is 2X better than 1.999X ??
My intuition here is that simple 2X scaling will just be about filling 4 pixels with the same color instead of 1, or something similar to this. I however dont have any intuition of 1.99X scaling. Hence the question that whether 2X is better than 1.99X.

Thanks !

Comment: Integer scaling may be faster, but that depends on the interpolation method. Quality should not change if integer or non-integer scaling is used.

Comment: The scaling algorithms employed by the browsers have to be able to accommodate non-integer scaling. I doubt that they choose different algorithms if the scale factor happens to be an integer. In any case simple replicating pixels produces a very blocky image which isn't optimal no matter how fast it is.